# Pip "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame"

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install PyGame with:`pip install pygame` it says

> Collecting pygame
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the
> requirement pygame (from versions: )
> No matching distribution found

I believe that I am using the most recent version, 8.1.1. I am using Python 3.5.1, on Windows 8.1. I have looked at other answers for this problem and none worked for me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried following their installation instructions? http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Pygame is not hosted on pypi and any answer here would restate installation process which is documented elsewhere.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen although I'm not sure this is on-topic, it's certainly NOT off-topic because the answer is "documented elsewhere." Unless that "elsewhere" is already on Stack Overflow (in which case this is a dupe), it's irrelevant.

Comment: Turns out it IS a dupe. The question boils down to "How can I install pygame" not "Why is pip telling me it can't find a version that satisfies the requirement <modulename>"

Comment: @AdamSmith every single answer on that question is basically link only. The close reason of "asking to find a off-site resource" is meant to prevent these kinds of questions, but it was not completely valid for this one since that was not quite what the op was asking.

Comment: I agree that "documented elsewhere" was not the best choice of words but I still feel that this and the one you marked this as a dup of are off topic for SO.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen "basically link only" isn't "link only." The accepted answer is decidedly *not* a link-only answer. I agree this isn't a good question, but it is answerable and there is a dupe target for it. This is far better than closing as off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update: Pygame [>=1.9.2](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/1.9.2/) should be installable via `pip`...

...for the major platforms (Windows included).

According to the [Getting Started](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) guide, the steps for [installation](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation) should be as simple as what the OP had attempted (way back in 2016):

```
pip install --user pygame
```

After installation, you can check if it was installed correctly by running one of the examples:

```
python -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

---

##### Why didn't this work before?

I was kinda curious as to why the OP was unable to install `pygame` back when this question was asked, so I looked into the history of `pygame` releases on pypi and noticed that the latest version available as of **May 2016** would have been version [`1.8.1`](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/1.8.1/), which was released in 2008 (yikes).

Not only that, but it didn't have any installable [wheels](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/1.8.1/#files), which explains why the OP contains that error from pip about being unable to find any versions to download.

#### Previous Answer (Still kinda relevant)

<s>`pygame` is not distributed via `pip`.</s> See [this link](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) which provides windows binaries ready for installation (*but only for pygame versions **less than 2.0.0***)

...Or follow the following instructions for manual installation of pygame (*version **1.9.4 and higher***)

1. [Install python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Make sure you have python on your [PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)
3. Download the appropriate wheel from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)
4. Install pip using [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)
5. Finally, use these commands to install pygame wheel with pip

- Python 2 (usually called pip)

  - `pip install file.whl`
- Python 3 (usually called pip3)

  - `pip3 install file.whl`

Comment: Thank you, however when I try to install "pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi" I cannot import PyGame in Python, and I cannot find a .whl file on the PyGame download site.

Comment: @nedla2004, Note that you downloaded the one that works with python 3.2, so make sure you are using python 3.2. If that doesn't fix it, get the `.whl` file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)

Comment: When I try 'pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl' it says 'pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is not a  supported wheel on this platform' and when I try'pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl' it seems like it worked, but when I try `import pygame` on the Python shell, it says `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'`

Comment: what is a `wheel`?

Comment: @Madivad https://pythonwheels.com/. Essentially, they are a way of packaging python projects for easy installation with a package manager such as pip.