# NameError: name 'json' is not defined

Tags: python, json, pip

Trying to import Json, my command is `pip install json`.
I'm working on windows 8.1

The error i'm getting in command prompt is

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements json <from versions:>
```

`No matching distribution found for json`.

and the error i'm getting on pycharm is

```
NameError: name 'json' is not defined
```

I tried importing `numpy` and it worked just fine .
I also did check [Pip "Could not find a that satisfies the requirement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125823/pip-could-not-find-a-that-satisfies-the-requirement)
and [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package)

Edit : Referred also to this link [Python 3.5.1 : NameError: name 'json' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001973/python-3-5-1-nameerror-name-json-is-not-defined) and getting an error that sudo is not recognized

Comment: Why are you trying to install it? It's part of the standard library, you don't need to install it.

Comment: What import statement are you using? It should be "import json"

Comment: "Trying to import Json, my command is pip install json" => importing and installing are not the same thing.

Comment: kindly check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001973/python-3-5-1-nameerror-name-json-is-not-defined

Comment: Use : pip install simplejson

Comment: It didn't work sam

Comment: As Daniel said, you don't need to install the `json` module, it's a standard module. If a simple `import json` doesn't work, then there's something seriously wrong with your Python installation.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If it's not defined in your code, you need to import it. This is exactly the same as *any* name in Python; you can't use something until you have defined it.

```
import json
```

Comment: That's quite awkward, i've put the import json in a try-catch by mistake.

Comment: No need to install, just import json

Comment: Folks, if you are working with airflow code, keep in mind that the code, as well python, can't have any "spaces" after declaring the variable (eg: response_filter=lambda response:json.loads(response.text),). So import the dependency and then delete any "abnormal" space between your variable(response_filter) and value(lambda response:json.loads(response.text),)). in other words, any spaces that you probably have on the edge of your "=". Just do a TRIM :)

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered a similar issue, pip failing to install json and math modules (using python 3.x).
Finally, I discovered that some modules you simply do not have to install - they are already BUILT-IN. :)
Of course, you still have to add "import json" at the top of your .py file.
Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command as simplejson instead of json like below,

**pip install simplejson**

If the above command also throwing an error Use the following command

**easy_install simplejson**

easy_install works sometimes if pip cannot serve the request.

Comment: Why not just rely on the json module from the standard library?

Comment: @ Jimmy same error is coming after using simplejson also as like json in previous case ?

Comment: @Serge simple json was added in python versions 2.6+. simplejson would work in all versions 2.4+ i guess