# Can't retrieve data from POST in django view

Tags: django, reactjs, post, axios

I have issue with retrieving data from POST in my django view. I send React form values with axios to my django backend. I believe data gets put into POST but somehow it seems that there isn't any data in POST and i can't access it in my django view. What could be issue here? (I can also see in my console that values are successfully submitted)

Source code:
**Django views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def send(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.body('name')
        send_mail('Test 1', data, 'austin.milk1@gmail.com', ['lowoko9513@gomail4.com',], fail_silently=False)
    return redirect('/api/')
```

**React form handling:**

```
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.elements.name.value;
        const email = event.target.elements.email.value;
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/send', {
            name: name,
            email: email
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(error => console.err(error));
    };
```

New error:

```
File "C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\Fitex#1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\Fitex#1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\Fitex#1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\Fitex#1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\Fitex5\backend\src\training\api\views.py", line 78, in send
    data = request.body('name')
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

Comment: This is because you're sending JSON and not FormData, the POST field is for forms. You want `request.body`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3020756/490790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're sending JSON and not FormData, the POST field is for forms. You want request.body.

Here's duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3020756/490790

### Further Update

You're trying to call a string (or bytes in this case) as a function. `request.body` is not a function. If you want to get a field you'll have to parse it as JSON and then access it like a dictionary.

```py
data = json.loads(request.body)
name = data['name']
```

Comment: But lastly how should i define json in my view: NameError: name 'json' is not defined?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413659/490790

Answer (score 0):

parameters send in axios post request can be retrieved from request.body.
Parameters = json.loads(request.body)

Now you can retrieve your parameters from this dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

You can also directly access by:

```
email = request.data['email']
name = request.data['name']
```

Comment: **This will only work for if you have `djangorestframework`** installed. By default Django has no idea how to unserialize JSON, you need to either do this manually or use DRF helpers.